# Appium 1.2.0.1 crashes on clicking "Tap" button in Appium Inspector- Windows 7

Tags: appium

Appium 1.2.0.1 crashes on clicking "Tap" button in Appium Inspector on Windows 7.

Below are the details:

Type of AUT: Native app

OS: Windows 7

Appium version: 1.2.0.1

using Real Device: Nexus 7

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/appium-discuss/Ex8O04qVfMI

Answer (score -1):

I also tried Appium Inspector in windows os.

Finally i came to know as it has not supported for windows os. we can work it on future, if they fixed.